# How to quote the command substitution in a for loop with a variable inside of it?

Tags: bash

Right now, my bash script isn't doing what I want it to. I run `bash -x script` on my bash script to debug it and its testing all of the directories and files in my current directory not a different directory specified by the user. Just tell me how I'm quoting the command substitution wrong that's where the problem is at. It's not looking at `$dir` variable when I run it.

Here's my script:

```
dir=$1
  
for i in "$(ls $dir)"
do
    if [ -d "$i" ]
    then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: For syntax errors, you can use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to analyse your script

Comment: Here, you have the following error : `for i in "$(ls $dir)" --> (error): Since you double quoted this, it will not word split, and the loop will only run once.`

Comment: Also, parsing ls [is a bad practice](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You should probably use somehting like : `for i in "$1"/*`

Comment: What exactly is the script **intended** to do? Finding all directories within $1?

Comment: Otherwise you also have an alternate solution using `find` command: `find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```sh
dir=$1

for f in "$dir"/* ; do
    test -d "$f" || continue
    echo "$f"
done
```

The important thing here is to not loop over `$(ls ...)` since it fails on special characters, but rather use a pattern in which `$dir` is protected with `""` but not the wildcard `*`.